# Quantum Mechanics Vs nonlocal causality

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, causality, non-locality

There is an article in [**Physics world.com**](http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/news/2016/aug/18/quantum-mechanics-trumps-nonlocal-causality) dated August 18, 2016, titled "Quantum Mechanics Trumps Nonlocal Causality.   The author of the article Philip Ball quotes one of the experimenters ( i.e. Ringbauer ) concluding the results of the new experiment imply back in time causality or many world interpretation. However after reading the article I do not see how this is obvious from the results of the experiment ( In fact I see no new results.) Since I am an interested hobbyist with a math background I do not have the training in Quantum Mechanics and perhaps cannot appreciate the conclusions.  Can someone of professional training please take a gander at this article and comment.

The full paper upon which the article is based  can be found at [**Nonlocal Causality**](http://advances.sciencemag.org/content/2/8/e1600162.full)

Comment: $\uparrow$ Link?

Comment: What the article actually says is 'The only way now that one might rescue some kind of classical (realist) causal interpretation of quantum correlations involves more radical revisions of Bell's assumptions, says Ringbauer – for example, backwards-in-time causation or a "many-worlds" interpretation of quantum mechanics with multiple parallel universes.'  In other words, if you want some classical model behind QM it has to be a very strange one.  What he is *not* saying is that he thinks such a model is correct, so he is *not* saying that the experiment implies such a model.

Comment: But things can be local without being classical. Entanglement or not. The realist interpretation is simply a variation of hidden classical variables controlling QM. I've read that paper recently and am not convinced on its physics.